# Connection string for addin in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins

I develop an addin for MSVS 2012. I need to get connection string for tsql tab currently opened.

I used IScriptFactory interface members to get connection string in MSVS 2010 (I use ServiceCache.ScriptFactory.CurrentlyActiveWndConnectionInfo.UIConnectionInfo property). IScriptFactory interface is defined in Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlTools.VSIntegration.VS.dll assembly.

For SSMS 2012 I use the same interface but defined in SqlPackageBase.dll assembly.

I can find neither Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlTools.VSIntegration.VS.dll nor SqlPackageBase.dll assemblies in MSVS 2012 (Ultimate RTM) installed folder.

Also I tried to find CurrentlyActiveWndConnectionInfo class and IScriptFactory interface in all MSVS 2012 assemblies installed but found nothing.

**How can I get connection string for current tsql tab in MSVS 2012?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLEditors.dll ("...\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions\Application\SQLEditors.dll
") assembly contains required information.
I tried to use ScriptFactory.Instance.CurrentlyActiveWndConnectionInfo property but it generates InvalidOperationException.
Here is the result of CurrentlyActiveWndConnectionInfo property disassembling:

```
public CurrentlyActiveWndConnectionInfo CurrentlyActiveWndConnectionInfo
{
    get
    {
        STrace.Params("ScriptFactory", "ScriptFactory.CurrentlyActiveWndConnectionInfo", string.Empty, null);
        if (ServiceCache.VSMonitorSelection == null)
        {
            STrace.LogExThrow();
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        return this.GetCurrentlyActiveWndConnectionInfo(ServiceCache.VSMonitorSelection);
    }
}
```

I think the problem in null ServiceCache.VSMonitorSelection.

Comment: Any chance you could post a code snippet for this? I am also interested in how the connection string can be retrieved :)